# add Custom field to Jomsocial group

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

I am using joomla's jomsocial & I want to add a custom field on group creation. Has anyone played with it before?

Answer (score 0):

jos_community_groups is the table where we have information related to jomsocial groups you will have to alter this table. com_community>templates>default>groups.create.php will be the file where you will need to add this new field. You need something else let me know. We have used it heavily.